# How to debug Linux kernel modules with QEMU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, qemu

I am working on academic project that modifies some `Kernel Networking` code as well as include a new `Kernel module`.

I am using QEMU to load modified kernel and test.

However, i find that a complete OS is required in some `.img` to debug.
Is it possible without it ?

Or, which is the distro that can be used with Kernel 2.6 for system. The distro need not have any features, except ability to run programs, including networking support.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to just boot kernel with custom init ram disk using KVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use buildroot
http://buildroot.uclibc.org/

clone it, configure it to use your custom kernel (default userspace is fine for a start, you might want to change it later).

it will build your kernel and root filesystem. the entire process takes about half an hour, twenty minutes of which is compiling the monster

my run line looks something:
qemu-system-i386
    -hda rootfs.ext2
    -kernel bzImage
    -m 512M
    -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0"
    -localtime
    -serial stdio

and some more options regarding a tap device

Answer (score 5):

**Minimal fully automated QEMU + GDB + Buildroot example**

QEMU + GDB on non-module Linux kernel is covered in detail at:  [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642) and building the kernel modules inside QEMU at: [How to add Linux driver as a Buildroot package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307328/how-to-add-linux-driver-as-a-buildroot-package/43874273#43874273) Get those working first.

Next, I have also fully automated GDB module debugging at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/1c29163c3919d4168d5d34852d804fd3eeb3ba67#kernel-module-debugging

These are the main steps you have to take:

1. Compile the kernel module with debug symbols:

   ```
   ccflags-y += -g -DDEBUG
   ```

   as mentioned at: [kernel module no debugging symbols found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298220/kernel-module-no-debugging-symbols-found/28298605#28298605)
2. Stop GDB with `Ctrl + C` and run:

   ```
   lx-symbols path/to/parent/of/modules/
   ```

   This amazing command, which is defined in a GDB Python script inside the Linux kernel source tree, automatically loads symbols for loaded modules present under the given directory recursively whenever GDB stops.

   The best way to make that command available is to use:

   ```
   gdb -ex add-auto-load-safe-path /full/path/to/linux/kernel
   ```

   as explained at: [GDB: lx-symbols undefined command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104491/gdb-lx-symbols-undefined-command/44095701#44095701)
3. `insmod` the kernel module.

   This must be done before setting breakpoints, because we don't know where the kernel will insert the module in memory beforehand.

   `lx-symbols` automatically takes care of finding the module location (in host filesystem and guest memory!) for us.
4. Break GDB again with `Ctrl + C`, set breakpoints, and enjoy.

If were feeling hardcore, you could also drop `lx-symbols` entirely, and find the module location after `insmod` with:

```
cat /proc/modules
```

and then add the `.ko` manually with:

```
add-symbol-file path/to/mymodule.ko 0xfffffffa00000000
```