# How to build and run a Linux kernel module on QEMU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, qemu

My teacher gives me a linux kernel vmlinuz-3.17.2 and a rootfs.ext2 which can be loaded to qemu. And he asks me to build a simplest kernel module which prints a hello world as homework.

- Firstly, I download the kernel source and run make oldconfig
- Secondly, I make the config to be PREEMPT and without modversions
  (according to uname -a of vmlinuz running in qemu) , then make prepare
- Thirdly, I compile the kernel mod and copy hello.ko in rootfs.ext2
- Finally, In qemu, I run insmod hello.ko which exit without any prompt
  and echo $? returns 0.

However, I can't see anything in dmesg or /var/log/messages
Is there anything wrong? How can I do with this?
There is also nothing to be printed when I run rmmod hello.ko successfully.

My log level is 7 4 1 7

I have make my hello.c as follows:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Hello World");
    return -1; 
// I changed this to -1 deliberately, Because It seems that the code is not executed.
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Buildroot**

Buildroot is the easiest way to do it:

- minimal out-of-tree example: [How to add a Linux kernel driver module as a Buildroot package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307328/how-to-add-a-linux-kernel-driver-module-as-a-buildroot-package/43874273#43874273)
- minimal in-tree example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/buildroot/tree/kernel-module-2016.05
- how to debug the module with GDB: [How to debug Linux kernel modules with QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607538/debugging-linux-kernel-module-on-qemu)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.