# GDB: lx-symbols undefined command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, centos7, debug-symbols

I am following the guide below:
[Debugging kernel and modules via gdb](https://docs.kernel.org/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html)

When I try to load the module symbols using the command below:
(gdb) lx-symbols

gdb says that the command is undefined.  How do I add these helper command to gdb?

gdb info: gdb-7.6.1-51.el7.x86-64 on Centos 7.0

Comment: what does `(gdb) apropos lx` show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the latest kernel sources (may be 4.0-rc4) or backport the [patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/609680/). Basically see if you have `script/gdb/` directory like [this](http://git.kiszka.org/?p=linux.git;a=tree;f=scripts/gdb;hb=refs/heads/queues/gdb-scripts) in your kernel sources. Because that is where you get these scripts.

Then you follow the steps mentioned in [Debugging kernel and modules via gdb](https://docs.kernel.org/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html)

Comment: I used 'git' to get the kernel source from git://git.kiszka.org/linux.git.  The script/gdb directory was there.  Verified that CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS and CONFIG_KGDB and other DBG flags were set in .config .  Compiled and installed the new kernel.  I read the Makefile and there was a reference to a vmlinux-gdb.py script.  However, I cannot find this script anywhere in the new kernel.  It stays in the build source tree.  How do I check if my build is correctly done?

Comment: Isnt it in the build source tree in `scripts/gdb/`

Comment: Yes, vmlinux-gdb.py is in the build source tree. Can I manually copy it to the new kernel tree?

Comment: What new kernel. You mentioned that you found the scripts/ directory. I already mentioned that if you can not see this code in the patch, you have to backport it. Yes you can try copying the scripts/gdb/ directory. Did you just downvote my answer?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote (i dont have enough points to vote either way).

Comment: The kernel source is directly from the author of the patch web site.  So script/gdb is there.  Next I compiled and installed this kernel ("new kernel") on the target computer (a VM running a host computer).  Do I also need to install the patched kernel on the host computer?

Comment: I do not understand why you need the scripts on target machine? Aren't these scritps supposed to do something with the build directory. See these two steps where you `cd /path/to/linux-build` and then `Start gdb: gdb vmlinux`. These are supposed to happen where you built the sources.

Comment: Here are the steps I did:
- Download the kernel source with the patch.
- Compile the kernel source.
- Load it on the VM computer.
- Start the VM computer.
- Run "gdb vmlinux" on the host computer.

Comment: - gdb stops at a break point.
- enter lx-symbols and get command not found.
and yes the kernel source contains the script/gdb folder (the latest snapshot of it).

Comment: I used the gdb command `info auto-load python-scripts` to actually see that the script was not loaded. The script symlink at the top-level directory was broken because I copied the build directory from a vm to my host in a different location and the symlink is actually an absolute path instead of being relative. Fixing the symlink using `ln -sf scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py` and reloading gdb fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

**`add-auto-load-safe-path`**

Usage:

```
gdb -ex add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/linux/kernel/source/root
```

Now the GDB scripts are automatically loaded, and `lx-symbols` is available.

Here is a [minimal fully automated Buildroot + QEMU example with detailed instructions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/1c29163c3919d4168d5d34852d804fd3eeb3ba67/rungdb#L20).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. In my case the issue raised because i haven't set the auto-load safe-path to ../scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py. so i  created ~/.gdbinit file added

```
add-auto-load-safe-path path/to/linux/kernel/tree/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py
```